# Http Connection Refused on Android

Tags: android

I am having a problem to connect to the server via android application which is running on a phone.

Why my browser on my phone can connect to the server, but my program  can not  connected to the server?   `org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.XX.XX:82 refused, network host unreachable etc etc`

Comment: Can you show us some code? How are you trying to connect to the server in your app?

Comment: Post code. PS: It's a local IP URL. First try to open this in your phone browser to see it works.

Answer (score 0):

For the possible case may occur check it.

Is that IP address accessible to outside world?

Just a guess: I think the IP address, you were using might have been reserved. It worked in emulator cause you were still in the network (probably in your office). As you came outside the network with your real device it didn't work.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> also check permission in manifest xml file.